# Changing the body content of email in Outlook Add-In

Tags: jquery, email, outlook, outlook-addin

Hi I am developing an outlook add-in using jQuery. I am trying to add the links to the contents of the emails in the main body. But I am not able to add the links. They only gives the option of known-entities and regular expression which do not fulfill my requirement.

For example let say I have the following emails.

> Hi I am trying to make the outlook plugin. Please help me on that.

And another email ::

> Hey outlook developers, I am too impatient to find the options of changing the email body in the
>   outlook plugin. Outlook plugins are cool

Now lets say i have the list of words `["Please", "body", "options", "outlook"]` to which I have to add links on my email body such that the emails should change
into ::

Email 1:

> Hi I am trying to make the [outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/) plugin. [Please](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/) help me on that.

and Email 2

> Hey outlook developers, I am too tired to find the [options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/) of changing
>   the email [body](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/) in the outlook plugin. [Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/) plugins are
>   cool

Is there any way I can achieve this in Outlook Desktop or Web in any platforms? Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

KnownEntities and RegexMatches are effective in these cases, you can check out [Contextual add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/contextual-outlook-add-ins), which will add links to the mail body and clicking on those links will open your add-in in place.

[image: contextual add-in opening in place]

If you just want to add a hyperlink to the body,
Web based add-in APIs does not support modification of mail body in read mode,
whereas you can use [Body APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook_1_6/office.body?view=office-js) in compose mode to manipulate the body.

If your scenario is only for read-mode, web-based add-in won't help.
For Windows-Outlook, you can create [VSTO add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/outlook-solutions?view=vs-2017) and to start with [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8481372/outlook-add-on-to-add-text-to-mail-body) should help you.